# how to log into existing user name which has active games

Tags: draw-something

I was playing draw something on my HTC but I wanted to start playing on my iPod touch. When I logged out of my HTC and logged in the my iPod all my games that I was playing were gone. How to I retrieve my existing games or log into my existing user name?